# How to install Psycopg2 for Python 3.5

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, python-3.5

I am trying the following command on Windows 7 using powershell

```
pip install psycopg2
```

And i am getting an error:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
>    Command "C:\Users\Piyush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Piyush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qe38dwoj\psycopg2\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Piyush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7bjug79j-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Piyush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-qe38dwoj\psycopg2

To intall Visuall C++, it requires Visual Studio to be installed.
Except for installing Visual Studio 2013.
Is there any other, that I can install Psycopg2 for **Python 3.5??**

Comment: Python 3.5 is alpha version, but you can download the Python 3.4 precompiled binary from  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue on Windows. I had to install a compiled version of it and then easy_install it.

You can find a compiled version of psycopg2 here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

And then do easy_install C:/locaiton/of/download.exe

That's what I do to install it on my Windows machine.

Comment: It does not contains complied version for Python 3.5

Answer (score 11):

Try this one. It worked for me

I Visited the http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and downloaded *psycopg2-2.6.1-cp35-none-win32.whl* file and copied it on *C:\*

later I activated my Virualenv by running this *C:\mydjango\django19\Scripts\activate* on the cmd which resulted to this *(django19) C:/>* and ran the following pip command, *pip install psycopg2-2.6.1-cp35-none-win32.whl* and the installation was successful.

> Note: Run the pip install psycopg2.......whl when you are in the current folder that has the psycopg2-2.6.1-cp35-none-win32.whl file via cmd

Comment: Same trouble, PyCharm 2016, Python 3.5. Tried this solution.
The import still didn't work, pressed "install package" in the IDE, and then the installation went smooth :)

Answer (score 1):

For Linux/Mac based you need to first install:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

and then install psycopg2:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

For me it worked in **DigitalOcean Linux 16.04 Production server**

Let me know if anyone got this correct!

Answer (score 0):

on **Mac** first

```
brew install postgresql
```

and then

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was occurring because the python path was not in environment variable. You can verify by typing python/python3 in your cmd and if the python shell is starting or not.

These different methods also worked for me at different times:

- check python path in environment variable.
- installing visual c++ 14 or latest.
- reinstalling python.
- installing binary or psycopg2 instead.
- install via easy_install.
- check by installing in global environment instead of virtual environment.
- try different psycopg2 version whl file.
  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg