# Installing psycopg2 osx 10.12 python 3.5.2 - Failed building wheel for psycopg2

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, psycopg2, python-3.5

I am having significant trouble installing psycopg2 in OSX. After installing Postgresql 9.5.4_1 using homebrew I attempted to install psycopg2 in my virtual environment: 
`pip install psycopg2`

I have also added pg_config to my path using `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.4_1/bin/pg_config`

Upon excecution I receive a number of errors including:

```
  ld: library not found for -lssl


 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

And

```
Failed building wheel for psycopg2
```

And

```
Command "/Users/*username*/.virtualenvs/report/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/9p/3_wdgjzd03d6bw1p_c9rrt6c0000gp/T/pip-build-cuplxne2/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/9p/3_wdgjzd03d6bw1p_c9rrt6c0000gp/T/pip-8gbk007q-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/*username*/.virtualenvs/report/bin/../include/site/python3.5/psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/9p/3_wdgjzd03d6bw1p_c9rrt6c0000gp/T/pip-build-cuplxne2/psycopg2/
```

Attempting to build from source results in similar errors...

Previous research and attempted solutions:

["Failed building wheel for psycopg2" - MacOSX using virtualenv and pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304833/failed-building-wheel-for-psycopg2-macosx-using-virtualenv-and-pip)

[How to install Psycopg2 for Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611808/how-to-install-psycopg2-for-python-3-5)

[How to install psycopg2 with "pip" on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420789/how-to-install-psycopg2-with-pip-on-python)

[Installing psycopg2 into virtualenv when PostgreSQL is not installed on development system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629368/installing-psycopg2-into-virtualenv-when-postgresql-is-not-installed-on-developm)

[Can't install psycopg2 with pip in virtualenv on Mac OS X 10.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678408/cant-install-psycopg2-with-pip-in-virtualenv-on-mac-os-x-10-7)

Thanks for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Homebrew's update of for OSX sierra. I was able to finally fix this issue by uninstalling and reinstalling python 3.5 and postgresql with homebrew and then trying to install psycopg2 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Homebrew's update of for OSX sierra. I was able to finally fix this issue by **uninstalling and reinstalling python 3.5 and postgresql with homebrew** and then trying to install psycopg2 again.

Answer (score 1):

My way for macosx sierra

Install psycopg2 globally, and then use it in virtualenv

```
pip3 install psycopg2
workon my_env #i use virtualenvwrapper
toggleglobalsitepackages #Enable global site-packages
```

In my case psycopg2 normally installed as global package, but isn't installed in virtualenv

Comment: Before reinstalling python3 and postgresql I couldn't install psycopg2 globally either. Now that its installed globally I can access it within in venv like you described. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mine broke with the Sierra 10.12.2 update.  Reinstalled/updated the command line tools and psycopg2 installed correctly.

xcode-select --install